# Mutate 2 vectors into a single vector in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a variable named Tactic (migratory tactics for a predatory species of fish) that contains three levels i.e "Migr", "OcRes", "EstRes" see data below:

```
combo1 <- structure(list(Sex = c("F", "M", "F", NA, "M", "F", NA, NA, "M", 
"F", NA, "M", "F", "F", NA, "F", "F", NA, "M", "F", NA, "M", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", NA, "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", 
"F", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "F", "F", NA, NA, NA, "M", "F", 
"F", NA, "F", "F", NA, NA, "M", "F", NA, "F", NA, "M", NA, "F", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "F", "M", "M", NA, "F"), Tactic = c("Migr", "Migr", 
"Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", 
"Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "OcRes", "Migr", "Migr", 
"Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "OcRes", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", 
"Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", 
"Migr", "EstRes", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", 
"Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", 
"Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "EstRes", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "EstRes", 
"Migr", "OcRes", "Migr", "EstRes", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", 
"Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr", "Migr")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-72L))
```

I want to reduce the data for 5-year-olds from 2018 only, and create a new column with EstRes (Estuary) and OcRes (Ocean Residents) renamed as Resident, and all others renamed as Migratory; so I can then plot and compare the average lengths (cm) of Residents versus Migrants. I think I am close but not quite there. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
avlen<-combo1 %>% 
      filter(Age_Year%in%5) %>%
      filter(Sample.Year%in%2018) %>% 
      droplevels() %>% 
      mutate(TacticB = case_when(Tactic = EstRes ~ Resident, Tactic = OcRes ~ Resident, TRUE ~ 'Migratory'))
      group_by(TacticB) %>% 
      summarise(avlen=mean(Length_cm), stdev=sd(Length_cm))
avlen
```

This is edited in from the comment:

```
avlen <-combo1 %>% filter(Age_Year%in%5) %>% 
      filter(Sample.Year%in%2018) %>% droplevels() %>% 
      mutate(TacticB = case_when(Tactic == "EstRes" ~ Resident, 
               Tactic == "OcRes" ~ Resident, 
               TRUE ~ as.character("Migratory"))%>% 
      group_by(TacticB) %>% 
      summarise(avlen=mean(Length_cm), stdev=sd(Length_cm))%>% 
      avlen   # and the editor is guessing that final `%>%` is not correct.
```

Comment: Your `combo1` example data only has `Sex` and `Tactic` variables, nothing called `Age_Year` or `Sample.Year` or `EstRes` or `Resident`, etc....

Comment: Haven't run your code, but I think you need `==`, not `=`, in your `case_when` conditions, and quotes around your literal strings (e.g. `"EstRes"`)

Comment: R is still not happy, the error is with the brackets but not sure where they need to be can you please rearrange the code to correct the bracket  ```
   avlen <-combo1 %>% 
        filter(Age_Year%in%5) %>%
        filter(Sample.Year%in%2018) %>% 
        droplevels() %>% 
        mutate(TacticB = case_when(Tactic == "EstRes" ~ Resident, 
                                   Tactic == "OcRes" ~ Resident, 
                                   TRUE ~ as.character("Migratory"))%>%
      group_by(TacticB) %>% 
      summarise(avlen=mean(Length_cm), stdev=sd(Length_cm))%>%
   avlen
```

Comment: DO NOT PUT CODE BLOCKS IN COMMENTS.  i  think the reasoning is probably explained in the help pages on how to ask questions and respond to comments. Do use the [edit]-ing facilities that SO kindly provides.

Comment: Thanks, https://stackoverflow.com/users/1855677/irtfm I wasn't aware of this...learning as I go along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this? I'm not sure that your sample data do not including many variables.

```
combo1 %>%
  filter(Age_Year == 5, Sample.Year == 2018) %>%
  mutate(TacticB = ifelse(Tactic %in% c("EstRes", "OcRes"), "Resident", "Migratory")) %>%
  group_by(TacticB) %>% 
  summarise(avlen=mean(Length_cm), stdev=sd(Length_cm))
```

Comment: Brilliant!! https://stackoverflow.com/users/16729175/park Thanks so much for clearly answering my question and most importantly providing the corrected script. Have an awesome day.